# Password only authentication in PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, passwords

Is it possible to authenticate a user in PHP/mySQL without requiring them to input their username ONLY their password?

I created a login authentication in Dreamweaver which checks users names against passwords in mySQL which works great! However, my boss doesn't want the user to have to type in their name. He just wants them to have to put in their unique code but then have their name displayed on the success page.

I thought perhaps I could simply hide the username input box and have it populate itself... could that be done with a recordset maybe?

If anyone could possible show me how I would very much appreciate it, thank you :)

Comment: Possible, yes. A good idea, no.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: what if two users have the same password?

Comment: I don't think this is a password in the typical sense, it is more like a token. These token are usually generated, hence there is no risk of two accounts having the same token. To be secure, the token has to be sufficiently long, so it cannot be guessed and the transport has to be secured (e.g. using TLS).

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone. There is no worry about security as it's a simple thank you page to people who agree to donate to a charity :) Everyone will have a unique code.

Yes, agreed Martin. I did search for promo-code authentication however, failed.

Comment: The best practice of authentication is to have a minimum of 2 things you need to remember when you want to login. When a server shows you a login challenge with a username and password, a possible hacker need to figure out two strings of data. But when you only use a password you make it very easy to hack into a application. But you can also use token-based authentication. Just ask your boss what he likes the most. A user can create his own token via his phone or other device where he is already logged in. So you have to login once to create a token for login on a intranet / website.

Comment: According to [DRAFT NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Authentication Guideline](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html): 
A password require an 8 character min or 6 random digits

Comment: @KoenHollander The user name is not considered secret and the entire difficulty to the attacker is an attack on the password which is slowed by an iterative password hashing method such as password_hash. Either the attacker is targeting a specific individual and thus knows the user name or is not interested a specific user but rather an entire DB of users perhaps for sale on the dark web.

Answer (score -1):

The best practice of authentication is to have a minimum of 2 things you need to remember when you want to login. When a server shows you a login challenge with a username and password, a possible hacker need to figure out two strings of data. But when you only use a password you make it very easy to hack into a application. But you can also use token-based authentication. Just ask your boss what he likes the most. A user can create his own token via his phone or other device where he is already logged in. So you have to login once to create a token for login on a intranet / website.

When you want to use only a password, just be sure you can find it in the database. Because some encryption algoritmes can't be reversed. So you can't "un"-hash a password for checking purposes.

When you use a token based authentication, you can create a application where the users logs in. Every x minutes (something like 5 or 10) the token expires and he needs to create another one. Every time he creates another code you can add it in the database to relate it to a user / useraccount.

When you only use a password for authentication a user a) can be hacked very easily because that will be the only thing a hacker needs to know. And with some bad luck two users can use the same password. Also with this solution you almost can't do it without plain-text passwords or a insecure reversible password encryption to check if the password is correct and related to the user.

But to answer your question.

Yes it is possible.

No it isn't safe
No it isn't the best practice

Comment: Thanks Koen. The reason behind not asking for username input is to make the process easier and more seamless for the user. I'm now thinking that if I use token based authentication then it is making it even more of a hassle for the user.

Comment: The user name is not considered secret nor is it considered a second security factor. The password should be hashed with `password_hash` and checked with `password_verify`, it should not be save the password in plain text or encrypted, it must be non-revertible.

Comment: As for the safety that is evaluated based on the threat model.